# How can I put markup between each MySQL field result?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making a comment box in PHP for my site. This is the code:

```
$con = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password); // Connect to MySQL database
if (!$con)
  {
  die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error()); 
  }
mysql_select_db($dbname);
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $comment=$_POST["comment"];
    $q="INSERT INTO comments_table (comments) VALUES ('$comment')"; // Could also be (\"comment\")
    mysql_query($q);
} 
$q="SELECT comments FROM comments_table";
$result=mysql_query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // List the comments - how could I get some markup between each to make each have it's own area?
    echo $row['comments']."";
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/comments-test.php">
<textarea name="comment" rows=30 cols=10></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to know is how I should go about making each comment have it's own box or markup. It can't be the same HTML between each comment (e.g., `,</div><div class="comment">`), otherwise there will be some comment box at the end of the comments that has no closing tag and a stray closing tag at the beginning. I am new to SQL, but not PHP. How should I do this?

Comment: You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection.  Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.  http://bobby-tables.com/php.html has examples to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll implement it ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  // List the comments - how could I get some markup between each to make each have it's own area?
    echo '<div class="comment">'.$row['comments']."</div>";
```

Would that work?

Comment: Yes, I have to wait 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're talking about, but do you mean something like:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // List the comments - how could I get some markup between each to make each have it's own area?
    echo "<div class='comment'>".$row['comments']."</div>";
}
```

if not, then I am not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I should have thought of it myself, a bit stupid of me.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your comment into the proper `div`s

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    // List the comments - how could I get some markup between each to make each have it's own area?
    echo '<div class="comment">', $row['comments'], '</div>';
}
```